# Re-entrancy Vulnerability?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens

```
   function transferFunds(uint _value) private {
        uint _fee = (3*_value)/(2*100);

        //Perform Ether transfer method
        merchant.transfer(_value - _fee);
        admin.transfer(_fee);
        emit LogForwardedEther(_value, merchant, _value - _fee, admin, _fee);
    }

   function transferFunds(address _token) private {
        uint _value = ERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint _fee = (3*_value)/(2*100);

        //Perform Token transfer method
        ERC20(_token).transfer(merchant, _value - _fee);
        ERC20(_token).transfer(admin, _fee);
        emit LogForwardedToken(_value, merchant, _value - _fee, admin, _fee, _token);
    }
```

Noticed that there's two separate **"Potential Violation of Checks-Effects-Interaction pattern"** in the above two functions, but i can't seem to find a better way of handling the state before executing transfer.

Hope someone out there could advise on this.

Thanks!

Comment: `i can't seem to find a better way of handling the state` - where exactly are you handling any state here?

Comment: @goodvibration sorry, i may have mistaken the check for balance as a state. Still new to Solidity. :/

Comment: Changing state = changing a contract variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on how paranoid you are.  These two functions are `private` and so the rest of your code may prevent reentrancy.  However if you really want to be safe you could introduce a mutex of some sort, like:

```
bool isTransferring = false;

function transferFunds(uint _value) private {
    require(isTransferring == false, "Rentrancy Detected");
    isTransferring = true;

    uint _fee = (3*_value)/(2*100);

    //Perform Ether transfer method
    merchant.transfer(_value - _fee);
    admin.transfer(_fee);

    isTransferring = false;

    emit LogForwardedEther(_value, merchant, _value - _fee, admin, _fee);
}
```

This approach is also a lot cheaper after the last hard fork with the changes to how SSTORE is priced.